# Passing by reference

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uikit

```
NSString *firstName2 = @"foo";
NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:firstName2, @"storeData", nil];

NSString * __strong *storeData = NULL;
storeData = &[dict objectForKey:@"storeData"];

*storeData = @"bar";
```

When setting `storeData`, I want that `firstName` will be changed as well.
I get a build error: `"address expression must be an lvalue or a function designator"`

How should I do it?

**EDIT**
In the big picture, I'm trying to create a subclass of UITextField that gets a reference to a variable and sets it in the textField:DidEndEditing method.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I want to pass a reference to NSString to another variable (NSString pointer of course), thus, changing storeData will change firstName as well.

Comment: @Rizon: you could create an UITextField subclass that has an standard delegate, a small controller.

Comment: @vikingosegundo, a small controller that does what exactly?

Comment: implement the UITextFieldDelegate

Comment: yeah but in case I have several textFields, how would I know what ivar to update each time the delegate is called?

Comment: each text field will ave it'S own delegate. Anyway: you asked for pass-by-reference. If you want help for creating an "integral" text field, you should ask a new question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you need to subclass `UITextField` to accomplish your goal.  In any case, the solution you are trying to implement has a philosophical flaw because it breaks encapsulation.

How to solve?  Your text fields are almost certainly owned by a view controller subclass.  So long as that object conforms to the `UITextFieldDelegate` protocol and each of the text fields has the controller object as its delegate, you should be good.  The only task remaining, then, is to map the text fields to a property on your controller or other object.

Let's assume for a second that your controller owns an instance of some data object whose properties you are trying to set with the controller's UI.  We'll call it `MyDataObject`:

```
@interface MyDataObject : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *firstName;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *lastName;

@end

@implementation MyDataObject
@end
```

To map the text fields to the properties on this object, you could do something like:

```
- (NSString *)propertyNameForTextField:(UITextField *)field {
    static NSDictionary *map;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        map = @{(id)self.fnField: @"firstName",
                (id)self.lnField : @"lastName" };
    });
    return map[field];
}
```

Then in our `UITextFieldDelegate` method, we do:

```
- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    [_dataObject setValue:textField.text forKey:[self propertyNameForTextField:textField]];
}
```

Note that I'm doing no error checking, validation, etc. etc.  This is just to show one way of mapping UI elements to properties they should affect.  This is on iOS; on Mac OS bindings are available for this use-case.

Answer (score 1):

That code doesn't make sense and C (Objective-C) doesn't work that way.

The return value of a method is generally in a register and, thus, has no address.   Even if it did, getting pointers to the innards of objects so you can muck with them directly is a really bad design pattern.

Comment: Can you come up with a better way to make a UITextField know which variable it needs to update in its delegate method?

Comment: @Rizon Ask a new question that focuses on what you are trying to do.